# Use object with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="place pin-red-big" data-place-id="place72">b</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    place72 = map.addMarker({
        lng: 10,
        lat: 10,
    });
    $('.place').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).data('place-id').setAnimation(null);
    });
    $('.place').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).data('place-id').setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    });
</script>
```

I need to be able to use the functions of the object place72, like `.setAnimation`.

Comment: `data('place-id')` returns a string, do you want to animate the string?

Comment: @BlackSheep ``data('place-id')`` returns: ``place72``. At the same time ``place72`` is the name of a object. I want to animate the object.

Comment: So you are looking for something like `window[$(this).data('place-id')].setAnimation(null);`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to access the `setAnimation()`-method of the object stored in the variable `place72`. Your approach was to store the variable name into a custom data attribute and use that name to access the variable.

This kind of doesn't work in JavaScript, but there are several easy solutions to your problem.

---

**1. Use the `data-place-id`-attribute as a dictionary key**

For this approach to work, you need a dictionary object where to store your created objects.

```
var dictionary = {
    place72 = map.addMarker({ lng: 10, lat: 20 })
};
```

Having this, you can easily access your markers as follows:

```
var key = $(this).data('place-id');
dictionary[key].setAnimation(...);
```

---

**2. Access global variables via the window object**

You don't neccessarily need to create dictionary object in approach one on yourself, as all globals variables can be accessed through the `window`-object. So access can be achieved as simple as follows:

```
var key = $(this).data('place-id');
window[key].setAnimation(...);
```

From a code-design-point-of-view, this is not the best approach for medium-sized or even larger projects though.

---

**3. Attach the desired object directly to the DOM**

It is also possible to store your object in the DOM-node itself. As you're apparently using jQuery, you can make use of its `data()`-method:

```
$('[data-place-id="place72"]').data('place', map.addMarker(...));
```

Accessing the object is just as easy:

```
$(this).data('place').setAnimation(...);
```

This is by far my favourite solution. (;

Comment: Good and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value doesn't refer to your variable, it's just a string, since the `place72` is a global variable you can access it by using bracket notation:

```
window[$(this).data('place-id')].setAnimation(null);
```

You can also use an object:

```
var places = {
    place72: map.addMarker({
        lng: 10,
        lat: 10,
    }),
    placeN: '...'
};

places[this.dataset.placeId].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want this...

```
var place72 = map.addMarker({
    lng: 10,
    lat: 10,
});
$('.place').mouseout(function(){
    place72.setAnimation(null);
});
$('.place').mouseover(function(){
    place72.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
});
```

The explanation is that place72 is initialized with map.addMarker, and contains your object.

**If setAnimation is an object public method of place72** , all you need is to request the method to place72.

To extend a bit this explanation, imagine an Object class called Foo. You initialized it (construct it, build it, instantiate it ) this way...

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

And now, the parameter foo its an instance of Foo.

So if Object class Foo has the public method Bar, you call it this way...

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
```

Notice that for static methods you would not request the method to the instance, but to the Object class itself. Like this;

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();

Foo.staticBarExample();
```

And finally, let me tell you that this is JavaScript theory (Object Oriented), not JQuery :)

Comment: `Foo::StaticBarExample();` It's not valid JavaScript? Is it PHP? Also how does this answer the question?

Comment: That was a typo! Fixed. This answer your question "I need to be able to use the functions of the object place72, like .setAnimation", and as I said, if method setAnimation is a valid function in place72, then you use place72.setAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your object is defined in which context you can simply get it like this:

```
var myOBJName= $(this).data('place-id');
var obj = mycontext[myOBJName];
```

know you can call the setAnimation function:

```
obj.setAnimation(/*...*/);
```

and it seems in your sample code `window` is the context object which your object is defined in it.

**BUT** what if your object is wrapped in another scope:

```
(function(){
    place72 = map.addMarker({
        lng: 10,
        lat: 10,
    });

    $('.place').mouseout(function(){
        //...
    });
    $('.place').mouseover(function(){
        //...
    });
})();
```

in these situations we usually are forced to use eval, whereas we know we better not use it:

```
(function(){
    place72 = map.addMarker({
        lng: 10,
        lat: 10,
    });

    $('.place').mouseout(function(){
        var myOBJName= $(this).data('place-id');
        //it would execute at the same context
        var obj = eval("_OBJ_="+myOBJName);
        obj.setAnimation(/*...*/);
    });
})();
```